# Animation doesn't play despite keys being set on bones through python

Tags: animation

I gather transformation matrices from different frames from an existing animation, these look different from different frames so it should be getting different matrices.

0 1
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.2682,  0.0946,  0.9587,  0.0826)
( 0.9129, -0.2929,  0.2843, -0.0179)
( 0.3077,  0.9515, -0.0078,  1.1148)
( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>

0 2
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.2897, -0.0161, 0.9570,  0.0955)
( 0.9472, -0.1484, 0.2843, -0.0579)
( 0.1374,  0.9888, 0.0582,  1.2448)
( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000,  1.0000)>
14 1
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.3268,  0.0632,  0.9430, 0.0797)
( 0.9379, -0.1011,  0.3318, 0.0645)
( 0.1163,  0.9929, -0.0262, 1.1392)
( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>

14 2
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.3418, -0.0561, 0.9381, 0.0884)
( 0.9380,  0.0413, 0.3443, 0.0507)
(-0.0581,  0.9976, 0.0385, 1.2749)
( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>

the first number is the frame and the second is the bone. Same bone at different frames have different values. These are used to transform another skeleton at in a loop that alters the timeline and inserts keyframes. But even after keys are on the bones the skeleton doesn't move when animation is played.

```
for frameIndex, frame in enumerate(sourceKeys):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        for boneIndex, bone in enumerate(sourceBoneNameList):
        
         Here I alter the bones



        targetPoseBoneList[boneIndex].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame)
            
        targetPoseBoneList[boneIndex].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", 
        frame=frame)
```

The bones have keys when I look in pose mode but they don't show when I look at the skeleton object.

UPDATE
Here are two images, the first I key locrotscale on all bones, in the second i have moved the head bone and repeat the same thing. But when going through the timeline nothing changes?

[image: skeleton]

[image: skeleton]

Comment: Without knowing what the `enumerate` is actually returning, I would guess that your calls to `keyframe_insert` are using `frame` when they need to use a frame number, maybe `frameIndex`.  If that's not it your problem is likely in the code that you omitted and replaced with "Here I alter the bones". There's no way to help you without knowing the type of `sourceKeys` and what goes on in the missing code.

Comment: I'm thinking I am keying the wrong thing, right now they end up on the posebones but nothing is shown in the skeleton.

Comment: I tried moving the bones and keying manually now but I get the same result, nothing happens when I play the animation despite there being keys on different frames and the bones being in different places.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use pose mode instead of edit mode instead somehow.